# Why can't data.table in R match the character string "Yes"?

Tags: r, string, boolean, data.table

I have a character column in a large data table. Something funky was happening. I traced it back to the third line of third following block finding 0 matching rows.

```
affected[PapBelowVoiceBox=="Not Recorded"|PapBelowVoiceBox=="Unsure",PapBelowVoiceBox:=NA_character_]
affected[PapBelowVoiceBox=="No",PapBelowVoiceBox:="cleardist"]
affected[PapBelowVoiceBox=="Yes",PapBelowVoiceBox:="involvdist"]
```

`variable=="Yes"` is not being returned as TRUE but `variable %like% "Yes"` is being returned as true.

So I tried to reproduce the data.table with a mini table and everything worked perfectly. So my question is, "What troubleshooting should I try?"

In other words, how could the following possibly happen?

```
> class(affected$PapBelowVoiceBox)
[1] "character"
> unique(affected[,PapBelowVoiceBox])
[1] NA          "cleardist" "Yes"      
> affected[,.N,by=PapBelowVoiceBox]
   PapBelowVoiceBox   N
1:               NA 488
2:        cleardist  96
3:              Yes  23
> affected$PapBelowVoiceBox=="Yes"
  [1]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [19]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [37]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [55]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [73]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [91]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[109]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE
[127] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[145] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[163]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[181] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[199] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[217] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[235]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[253]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[271]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[289]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[307]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[325]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[343]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA
[361]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[379]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[397]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[415]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[433]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[451]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[469]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[487]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[505]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[523]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[541]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA
[559]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[577]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[595]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
> affected[PapBelowVoiceBox %like% "Yes",.N]
[1] 23
> affected[PapBelowVoiceBox == "Yes",.N]
[1] 0
```

Comment: Most likely an issue due to the new experimental feature automatic indexing, which can be turned off by doing `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. And all reported bugs have been [fixed since in devel 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), including this - seems like the ones reported before.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am using package version 1.9.4. So if I install from github then I should eliminate the problem. Is that correct?

Comment: @Arun: i produced a sample table in 1.9.4 and it worked fine... what is it in this case that's causing the issue with indexing?

Comment: Farrel, yes, install from github should fix the issue. It's due to a bug in a new (and awesome) feature - where data.table attempts to create an index automatically (secondary keys) which allows binary search based subset instead of vector scan, automatically, using native R-syntax. For now, DT[x == .] and DT[x %in% .] are both optimised. Wie'll generate vignettes before the 1.9.8 release to get these clear. Will write back. Please remind me if I don't :-).